# Can anyone tell me how to solve this GED Math problem?

Tags: learning

A cookie recipe that makes 24 cookies call for the following ingredients:
2 3/4 c. Flour     1 1/3 c. Sugar.

3/4 c. Butter

1 egg   3 1/2 t. Baking powder  1 1/2 t. Vanilla extract

Amy is hosting a party and will have 16 people in attendance, including herself. She wants to make one large batch of cookies 
to accommodate everyone. If each person will eat three cookies, what are the new amounts that Amy must measure for each ingredient?

I’ve been trying to figure it out for a couple of days now!
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Have you figured out how many cookies Amy needs to make for the $16$ people at the party?

Comment: Please add [more context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/272831) to your question. Include things such as what you've done with the problem. Your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453822/272831) suffers from the same issue. That is, please make your post more constructive rather than saying things such as "I swear, if someone knows the answer, I’d feel really stupid. " (and imho leave the emojis out)

Comment: Yeah. Amy needs to make 48 cookies.

Comment: $16$ people times $3$ cookies/person is $48$ cookies.  You just need to double the recipe for $24$ cookies.

Comment: I know I have to double the recipe.... but how do I double the recipe and what would be the new measurements for the ingredients?

Comment: To double the recipe, you multiply the amount of each ingredient by $2$.

Comment: $(2\frac 34)\times 2 = (2 + \frac 34)\times 2 = 2\times 2 + \frac 34\times 2 = 4+ \frac 64 =4 + \frac {4 + 2}{4} = 4 + \frac 44 + \frac 24 = (4+1) + \frac {2\times 1}{2\times 2} = 5\frac 12$.

Comment: Or  $2\frac 34 = 2 + \frac 34 = \frac {2\times 4}{4} + \frac 34 = \frac {2\times 4+3}4 =\frac {11}4$.  So $2\frac 34\times 2 = \frac {11}{4}\times 2 =\frac {11\times 2}4 = \frac {11\times 2}{2\times 2}=\frac {11}2 \times \frac 22 = \frac {11}2 = \frac {10 + 1}2 =\frac {10}2 + \frac 12 = 5 +\frac 12 = 5\frac 12$.

Comment: "I know I have to double the recipe...."  You should say that in the question.  A lot of people would have that be a hard part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) How many cookies does she need?

$16$ people and $3$ cookies each is $16\times 3 = 48$ cookies.

2) How many cookies does one recipe make?

One recipe makes $24$ cookies.

3) If she makes $k$ recipes how many cookies does $k$ recipes make?

Each recipe makes $24$ cookies so $k$ recipes make $24 \times k$ cookies.

4) How many recipes must she make to make enough cookies?

$k$ recipes make $24\times k$ cookies.  And she needs $48$ so you needs to make however many $k$ is so that $24 \times k = 48$.

So solve that:

$24 \times k = 48$ so

$24\times k \div 24 = 48 \div 24$

$k = 2$.

5) If she needs to make $2$ recipes worth what does she need to do to the ingrediant to make one recipe become $2$ recipes worth?

She must multiple every ingredient by $2$.

6)   What are the new amounts when they are multiplied by $2$.

$2 \frac 34\times 2$ c. Flour

$1 \frac 13\times 2$ c. Sugar.

$\frac 34 \times 2$ c. Butter

$1\times 2$ egg

$3 \frac 12\times 2$ t. Baking powder

$1 \frac 12\times 2$ t. Vanilla extract

7) What are those values?

What is $2\frac 34 \times 2$?

a) Put the mixed fraction as an improper fraction:

$2 \frac 34 = 2 + \frac 34 = \frac 21 + \frac 34 = \frac 21\times \frac 44 + \frac 34 = \frac {2\times 4}4 + \frac 34 = \frac 84 + \frac 34 = \frac {8+3}4 = \frac {11}{4}$.

b) Multiple by $2$ by putting multiplying the numerator by $2$.

$\frac {11}4 \times 2 = \frac {11\times 2}{4}$.

!!!ADVICE!!!! Do *NOT* multiply $11 \times 2$ yet.  Wait!  You may have to cancel out common factors so there is *no* point multiplying yet if you will just have to divide out later!

c)  Find any common factors between the numerator and the denominator.

Denominator $4= 2\times 2$ and the numerator $11\times 2 = 11 \times 2$.  $11$ can't be broken any further.

So we have $\frac {11\times 2}{4} = \frac {11\times 2}{2\times 2}$

d) Cancel common factors

$\frac {11\times \color{red}2}{2\times\color{red}2}=\frac {11}2\times \frac {\color{red}2}{\color{red}2} = \frac {11}2\times \color{red}1 = \frac {11}2$.

e) Reduce to mixed fraction.

$\frac {11}2 = \frac {10+1}{2} = \frac {2\times 5 + 1}{2} = \frac {\color{red}2\times 5}{\color{red}2} + \frac 12 = 5+\frac 12 = 5\frac 12$.

f) You are done. $5\frac 12$ c.Flour

The rest:

$1\frac 13= \frac 33 + \frac 13 = \frac 43$.

$\frac 43 \times 2 = \frac {4\times 2}3 = \frac 83$.

$\frac 83 = \frac {6+2}3 = \frac {2\times 3 + 2}3 =\frac {2\times 3}3 + \frac 23=2+\frac 23 = 2\frac 23$

So $2\frac 23$ cups sugar.

$\frac 34\times 2 = \frac {3\times 2}{4} = \frac {3\times 2}{2\times 2} =\frac 32$

$\frac 32 = \frac {2 + 1}2 = \frac 22 + \frac 12 = 1\frac 12$ butter.

$1\times 2 = 2$ so $2$ eggs.

$3\frac 12 = 3+\frac 12 = \frac {3\times 2}2 + \frac 12 = \frac {2\times 3 +1}2 =\frac 72$.

$\frac 72 \times 2 = \frac {7\times 2}2 = 7$ so $7$ teaspoons baking powder.  (Actually when you double a recipe you are only suppose to multiply the powder by one and a half....)

And $1\frac 12 \times 2 = 3$.  (I'm tired of typing.)

Comment: Thank You SO MUCH for taking the time to help me. You wrote so much and explained this math problem so precisely. I really appreciate it! ❤️